# Django mod_wsgi and haystack = error 500

Tags: django, mod-wsgi, django-haystack

I'm using Haystack on my Django project and all works well using django server. When I'm going to production, running on Apache, I receive an error 500; more precisely from the log:

```
mod_wsgi (pid=4536): Exception occurred processing WSGI script 

'/opt/local/apache2/htdocs/meishi/meishi/wsgi.py'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
[Wed Apr 25 13:41:52 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Django-1.4/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 241, in __call__
[Wed Apr 25 13:41:52 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     response = self.get_response(request)
[Wed Apr 25 13:41:52 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Django-1.4/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 179, in get_response
[Wed Apr 25 13:41:52 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())
[Wed Apr 25 13:41:52 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Django-1.4/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 221, in handle_uncaught_exception
[Wed Apr 25 13:41:52 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
[Wed Apr 25 13:41:52 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Django-1.4/django/views/debug.py", line 66, in technical_500_response
[Wed Apr 25 13:41:52 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     html = reporter.get_traceback_html()
[Wed Apr 25 13:41:52 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Django-1.4/django/views/debug.py", line 276, in get_traceback_html
[Wed Apr 25 13:41:52 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     return t.render(c)
[Wed Apr 25 13:41:52 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Django-1.4/django/template/base.py", line 140, in render
[Wed Apr 25 13:41:52 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     return self._render(context)
[Wed Apr 25 13:41:52 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Django-1.4/django/template/base.py", line 134, in _render
[Wed Apr 25 13:41:52 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     return self.nodelist.render(context)
[Wed Apr 25 13:41:52 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Django-1.4/django/template/base.py", line 823, in render
[Wed Apr 25 13:41:52 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     bit = self.render_node(node, context)
[Wed Apr 25 13:41:52 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Django-1.4/django/template/debug.py", line 74, in render_node
[Wed Apr 25 13:41:52 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     return node.render(context)
[Wed Apr 25 13:41:52 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Django-1.4/django/template/debug.py", line 84, in render
[Wed Apr 25 13:41:52 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     output = self.filter_expression.resolve(context)
[Wed Apr 25 13:41:52 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Django-1.4/django/template/base.py", line 599, in resolve
[Wed Apr 25 13:41:52 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     new_obj = func(obj, *arg_vals)
[Wed Apr 25 13:41:52 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Django-1.4/django/template/defaultfilters.py", line 718, in date
[Wed Apr 25 13:41:52 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     return format(value, arg)
[Wed Apr 25 13:41:52 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Django-1.4/django/utils/dateformat.py", line 310, in format
[Wed Apr 25 13:41:52 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     return df.format(format_string)
[Wed Apr 25 13:41:52 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Django-1.4/django/utils/dateformat.py", line 33, in format
[Wed Apr 25 13:41:52 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     pieces.append(force_unicode(getattr(self, piece)()))
[Wed Apr 25 13:41:52 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Django-1.4/django/utils/dateformat.py", line 214, in r
[Wed Apr 25 13:41:52 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     return self.format('D, j M Y H:i:s O')
[Wed Apr 25 13:41:52 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Django-1.4/django/utils/dateformat.py", line 33, in format
[Wed Apr 25 13:41:52 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     pieces.append(force_unicode(getattr(self, piece)()))
[Wed Apr 25 13:41:52 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Django-1.4/django/utils/encoding.py", line 71, in force_unicode
[Wed Apr 25 13:41:52 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     s = unicode(s)
[Wed Apr 25 13:41:52 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Django-1.4/django/utils/functional.py", line 121, in __unicode_cast
[Wed Apr 25 13:41:52 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     return func(*self.__args, **self.__kw)
[Wed Apr 25 13:41:52 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Django-1.4/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 86, in ugettext
[Wed Apr 25 13:41:52 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     return _trans.ugettext(message)
[Wed Apr 25 13:41:52 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Django-1.4/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 278, in ugettext
[Wed Apr 25 13:41:52 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     return do_translate(message, 'ugettext')
[Wed Apr 25 13:41:52 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Django-1.4/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 268, in do_translate
[Wed Apr 25 13:41:52 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     _default = translation(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
[Wed Apr 25 13:41:52 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Django-1.4/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 183, in translation
[Wed Apr 25 13:41:52 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     default_translation = _fetch(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
[Wed Apr 25 13:41:52 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Django-1.4/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 160, in _fetch
[Wed Apr 25 13:41:52 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     app = import_module(appname)
[Wed Apr 25 13:41:52 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Django-1.4/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
[Wed Apr 25 13:41:52 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     __import__(name)
[Wed Apr 25 13:41:52 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] ImportError: No module named haystack
[Wed Apr 25 13:41:52 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /opt/local/apache2/htdocs/favicon.ico
```

Before using Haystack on my project, I had no problems at all with mod_wsgi, all worked well.
What could be the problem?

Comment: Provide the actual trace back and exception message from the error log, not just the one line message from before it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error indicates that the 'haystack' module is not installed into the Python installation that mod_wsgi is using. Work out where you installed the 'haystack' module and ensure it is the same Python installation as mod_wsgi is using.

Comment: I had same issue, and knowing the meaning of the error definitely helps solving the issue. Mine was a stupid mistake, I hadn't activated my virtual environment where haystack was installed.